# Gravity Forms Upload each entry to Unique Folders

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

When someone uses my form, they can upload upto 15 images.

I have about 10 - 20 uploads a day, which means that i could get upto 150-300 images per day.

The issue i've got is with where these images are stored. ALl in the /uploads/ folder without any reference to who uploaded them.

Is it possible to move these uploads into a unique folder, named after the entryID of the submitted form, maybe with another field name, so:

`../uploads/gravity/[firstname]_[entryID]/[uploads here]`

If this is possible, then I can use an FTP client to access each entry & all the relevent files with ease, without needing to log into wordpress and click through each entry.

#### Note:

I'm also using Zapier at the moment to take these files & put them in their own folder, but this is costing me month fee because there are so many entries. If I can do it all on my own site, this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code that will get you at least half way there:

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/35b86c47cdf0124be735

Changes you'll need to make:

1. Also stash the current `$entry` object in the `stash_current_field_id()` method.
2. Use the stashed `$entry` to modify the file upload path in the `modify_file_upload()` method.

Comment: David - where does that go need to go? Does it goes somewhere inside of the Gravity Forms code, or just into the functions file?

Comment: The theme's functions.php file is the easiest. You can also include it in your own custom plugin or via the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin.

Comment: Note, when you do this, deleting entries will not delete the custom folders and files.